# Images to be placed after three posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I want to place an image at the fifth position while displaying the articles in home page. Say I have set the posts to display 14 in home page and the fifth and tenth position the same image has to be placed in between the posts. Below is the code I am modifying it.

```
<?php 
if( ( $wp_query->current_post + 1) % 2 == 0 ) { 
    echo '</div>
          <div class="post-row">
            <article id="post-777" class="group grid-item post-777 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-health-media">
              <div class="post-inner post-hover">
                <div class="post-thumbnail"><img width="520" height="245" src="http://xyz.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/shutterstock_137498780-520x245.jpg" class="attachment-thumb-medium size-thumb-medium wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://xyz.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/shutterstock_137498780-520x245.jpg 520w, http://healthpick.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/shutterstock_137498780-720x340.jpg 720w" sizes="(max-width: 520px) 100vw, 520px"></div>
              </div>
            </article>'; 
}; 
endwhile; 
echo '</div>'; 
?>
</div><!--/.post-list-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can you suggest where I am going wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to put image after 5th or 10th position just change the logic here

```
if( ($wp_query->current_post) % 5 == 0 )
```

Comment: `$wp_query->current_post` returns an int, why are you passing it to `count`?

Comment: thank bro. sorry was not in head. anyways thank to pointing the mistake :)

Comment: What could be the logic I am missing it?

Comment: @Exprator the logic which you said is not working. This is my website healthpick.in

Comment: you said after 5th image right you want to place the image? so here it will check 5/5 and give you the remainder as 0, if it gets 0 it will print the image else not